# What is the meaning of 顔で聞いてる?

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-で

I was getting some new vocabulary using My First Story's song called アンダーグラウンド and then I couldn't understand the meaning of the verse 全部 同じ顔で聞いてるけど, how can you listen with your face? Is there another meaning for 聞くthan to hear?

The song is available [here](https://youtu.be/S1Sm9OiVWkE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there another meaning for 聞くthan to hear?

There is ('to ask'), but I don't think it's relevant here.

The verse in the song goes:

「ずっと嘘吐いてばっかだ」とか

「どっか頭オカシイんじゃない」とか

全部 同じ顔で聞いてるけど

そうじゃない

そうじゃない

'[They say] "You're always telling nothing but lies", or "You must be crazy", and I listen to it all *with the same face [expression]*, but it's not true, it's not true'

全部、同じ顔で聞いてる here means the speaker simply always listens with the same look on their face. Reading the title, by the way, I kind of thought it might be something like 'the question is written on someone's face', with the 'to ask' meaning, but looking up the lyrics that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it's clear the meaning!